# I have a set of coordinates being plotted for a soccer field but there is a line going off the map, I cant find where the issue is

Tags: python

[image: A screenprint of the end result as currently shown]

```
pitch = Pitch(pitch_color='green')
fig, ax = pitch.draw()
```

#Attempt 2 !!!! Append the first point to the end to complete the circle I guess, once its sorted out

```
alistx = list(map(int,dfs\['endX'\]*1.2))
alistx.append(alistx\[0\])
alisty = list(map(int,dfs\['endY'\]*.8))
alisty.append(alisty\[0\])
alistx
```

#If the plot wont flip on its own just switch the `x` and `y` in the scatter and fill functions to flip them manually

```
plt.scatter(alistx, alisty)
plt.fill_between(alistx, alisty, color = 'red' , alpha = .3)
print(alistx , alisty)
```

Just help me get rid of the line please, if you know of a better way to do this for compatibility with `mplsoccer` then that helps too.

[Sample PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzFfm.png)

Comment: What is the value od `dfs`? Please add it to your question.

Comment: What would be the correct argument values for `fill_between`? Please add it to your question. Try them,show us the correct output image.

Comment: dfs is a dataframe things like the minute and then the starting 'x' and 'y' along with the 'endX' and 'endY' that are shown as the 2 lists above the graphic. The list starting with [48 is the X coordinate and the one staring in [34 is the Y. I am trying to use the scatter plot function to get the points then fill to get the area between the points filled in, its like the append is making it so that instead of it making a set pair for them they are being paired with a created 0 rather than x matching with the appended y

Comment: Can you draw  a filled triangle correctly by passing constant integers to `fill_between`? Please post the code and the screenshot of the correct triangle. As soon as that works, it would be easy to figure out what's wrong your (more complicated) plot.

Comment: I have a simple triangle with the code working as the hyperlink labeled Sample PNG,

Comment: I got the color issue resolved by using facecolor instead, now the issue is how to find a way to sort the points to make it so that they connect on the outermost points because if they double back on themselves it removes the coloring..

Comment: Your code (both the triangle and the shape on the football field) seems to be correct. I was able to draw the shape with those coordinates correctly (without the extra horizontal and vertical lines) using a different graphics library. So maybe `fill_between` is buggy or you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.fill` ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html), [call example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-py)) instead of `plt.fill_between`. First draw a triangle, then draw your more complicated polygon.